# Find value for column where value for a separate column is maximal

Tags: python, pandas, max

If I have a Python Pandas DataFrame containing two columns of people and sequence respectively like:

```
  people   sequence
    John      1
    Rob       2
    Bob       3
```

How can I return the person where sequence is maximal?  In this example I want to return 'Bob'

Comment: `df.set_index('people').sequence.idxmax()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `pandas.Series.idxmax`

Is the method that tells you the index value where the maximum occurs.

Then use that to get at the value of the other column.

```
df.at[df['sequence'].idxmax(), 'people']

'Bob'
```

I like the solution @user3483203 provided in the comments.  The reason I provided a different one is to show that the same think can be done with fewer objects created.

In this case, `df['sequence']` is accessing an internally stored object and subsequently calling the `idxmax` method on it.  At that point we are accessing a specific cell in the dataframe `df` with the `at` accessor.

We can see that we are accessing the internally stored object because we can access it in two different ways and validate that it is the same object.

```
df['sequence'] is df.sequence

True
```

While

```
df['sequence'] is df.sequence.copy()

False
```

On the other hand, `df.set_index('people')` creates a new object and that is expensive.

Clearly this is over a ridiculously small data set but:

```
%timeit df.loc[df['sequence'].idxmax(), 'people']
%timeit df.at[df['sequence'].idxmax(), 'people']
%timeit df.set_index('people').sequence.idxmax()

10000 loops, best of 3: 65.1 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.6 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 556 µs per loop
```

Over a much larger data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    people=range(10000),
    sequence=np.random.permutation(range(10000))
))

%timeit df.loc[df['sequence'].idxmax(), 'people']
%timeit df.at[df['sequence'].idxmax(), 'people']
%timeit df.set_index('people').sequence.idxmax()

10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 816 µs per loop
```

The relative difference is consistent.

Comment: I like this better than `set_index`. It's clearer what you're doing IMO.

Comment: I appreciate both answers but the written context provided with the second answer is what made me identify it as the solution.  thx

Comment: @user3483203 It was an opportunity for me to point something out (-: